# Dynamic binding of class based on index in v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

```js
<transition-group appear name="fade" class="row no-gutters" v-if="currentTab === 'living'">
    <div class="col-6 pr-3 pb-3" :class="[ isEven(index) ? 'col-md-8' : 'col-md-4']" v-for="(item, index) in livingGallery" :key="'living' + index">
      <img :src="item.photoThumbSmall" alt="Gallery Photo index" class="d-block w-100">
    </div>
</transition-group>
```

This is the code for isEvent:

```js
methods: {
    isEven(i) {
      return i / 2 === 0;
    }
},
```

I need to render the `div` different based on the `index`. `div` with even `index` gets the class `col-md-8`, otherwise `col-md-4`.

This is what I expected from the code:

```
index 0 => col-md-8
index 1 => col-md-4
index 2 => col-md-8
......
```

However, only the first element has `col-md-8`. The remaining elements are assigned `col-md-4`.

What's the problem?

Comment: Can you show us the code for `isEven`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do `i` modulus `2`, not divided by `2`.

```js
isEven(i) {
    return i % 2 === 0;
}
```

`i / 2` will only ever be `0` if `i` is `0`. Since you want to know whether the given index is even, you should check the remainder of the division, which is what the modulus operation returns.